# How to force method param value to be an element of an Interface

Tags: typescript

I want to force method param value to be any element of an `Interface`.

For example,

I've an `Interface` like this

```
interface User {
  userId : number;
  userName : string;
}
```

and the param should be either `userId` or `userName`. So I defined the method like this

```
setUserState = (key : User , newValue : string) => {
      // Some code here
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work. So I tried `key : Partial<User>`, which doesn't work.

I know it can be achieved like this

```
setUserState = (key : 'userName' | 'userId' , newValue : string) => {
   // Some code here
}
```

but the problem is, when ever I update the `User` interface with new `element`, I'd have to update the method signature also. That's point less.

So, What's the perfect way to force param value to be an element of an `Interface` ?, Is it possible ?

**Edit 1**

Is there any `AnyOf<User>` kinda operators ?

**Edit 2**

I am using `Version 2.9.2`

NOTE: I am new in `TypeScript`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `keyof` operator to restrict the first parameter to be one of the `User` properties. Then you can use type query to restrict the second parameter to have an appropriate type:

```
interface User {
    userId: number;
    userName: string;
}

const user: User = { userId: 1, userName: 'userName' };

const setUserState = <TKey extends keyof User>(key: TKey, newValue: User[TKey]) => {
    user[key] = newValue;
}

setUserState('userId', 1);
setUserState('userId', '1'); //Error '"1"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'
setUserState('foo', 1); //Error - '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"userName" | "userId"'
```

Generics is used to be able to reuse the key type (property name) in property value type query (`User[TKey]`).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20userId%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20userName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20user%3A%20User%20%3D%20%7B%20userId%3A%201%2C%20userName%3A%20'userName'%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20setUserState%20%3D%20%3CTKey%20extends%20keyof%20User%3E(key%3A%20TKey%2C%20newValue%3A%20User%5BTKey%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20user%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20newValue%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AsetUserState('userId'%2C%201)%3B%0D%0AsetUserState('userId'%2C%20'1')%3B%20%2F%2FError%20'%221%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'number'%0D%0AsetUserState('foo'%2C%201)%3B%20%2F%2FError%20-%20'%22foo%22'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20parameter%20of%20type%20'%22userName%22%20%7C%20%22userId%22')

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
interface User {
 readonly userId?: string;
 userName?: string;
 anyotherElement?: string 
}
```

Note: add `?` just after `:` to make it optional

then you can send direct  User as parameter

```
 setUserState = (user: User) => {
       can access with `user.userId`
       // Some code here
    }
```

Comment: The properties can't be optional. I am sorry , I didn't mentioned it in my question.

Comment: then you can not use User interface but a simple way to set `param:string` in function

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Is there any `AnyOf<User>` kind of operators  ?

Comment: No there is no such options. Please also mention the typescript version yiu are working with, new features added in latest versions.

Comment: @pro-means, There's similar functionality available , https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055038/4370279

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. I was not aware about

Answer (score 1):

Let's try it this way first:

```
interface User {
    userId : number;
    userName : string;
}

const cur: User = {userId: 0, userName: 'root'}

const setUserState = (key : keyof User , newValue : string) => {
    cur[key] = newValue;
    // note: no error here, but this is erroneous,
    // as cur['userId'] is number, and newValue is string!
}

setUserState('userId', '0');
setUserState('userName', 'root');
setUserState('wrong', 'wrong');
```

Note the comment inside the function: it shows that, for the one hand, the `keyof` type definition is entirely normal to access the fields of `User` object by this key, but, for the other hand, you'll have to handle all type checks for particular fields yourself. TypeScript won't be able to check the `newValue` parameter type to match the corresponding field of `User`.

Comment: Ok. That's one valuable information for me. (y) Thank you for the response.